# A Trivial Pursuit #14 (Entertainment 3/4): Integration by Parts

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, music

<sub>This is part 14 of [A Trivial Pursuit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20is%3aq%20%22a%20trivial%20pursuit%22&searchOn=3), a 25-part puzzle hunt. Each part is solvable on its own, with the exception of the meta-puzzle at the end.</sub>

---

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1975 | FLON ERE INCEL ANY DOT HUE MANC HINGE | 2018 |
| 2022 | BARACK SCT TREE TIC MOB NO KEY SYS | 1999 |
| 1982 | MIMYC CHA HEEL JAM I CAL ROCK MANS ONCE | 2002 |
| 2010 | SAGO RIMS MILL TAZH | 2014 |
| 1997 | GRAD U IONS HEN ROSA DES | 1991 |
| 1982 | SNIT EVE MR VILLA ERN BAN AD | 1993 |
| 2015 | THEZE BE BRA HATE LEADS | 1970 |
| 1978 | KASHA BOTCH IO COLA ANTE | 2011 |
| 2001 | LIRY SANAA LOPED SAMS | 2014 |
| 1981 | SMILE SOD FAT VIC SELL | 1969 |
| 2004 | KALI ISLE WARY CHINE FES | 2007 |
| 2006 | SURF JEDHA NOTCH IS LITE PEV PENS PERS | 2006 |
| 1987 | GEM ORE TAG EMIL LICH CAELA | 1988 |
| 2005 | MAGA BRIER I AH CLARE LYE | 1999 |
| 1977 | MEN AT LION AS I MOAN EF | 1965 |
| 2013 | JEF SLEET WOOS DIME JAC | 1977 |
| 1987 | UK ANY EWE 2ST | 2013 |
| 1987 | PRINT HE CEDAR K NESS | 2017 |

**The answer is 5 letters long.**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The items in the middle column are

> musical bands/artists that have their letters intertwined. For example, towards the bottom, we have UKANYEWE2ST, which is pretty clearly U2 and KANYE WEST. Here they all are:
>
>  *FLO***N E***RE* **I***NCE***L** *AN***Y** *D***O***T H***U***E MA***N***C HIN***G***E* - *FLORENCE AND THE MACHINE* and **NEIL YOUNG**
>  *B***AR***ACK S***CT** *TREE T***IC MO***B* **N***O* **KEY S***YS* - *BACKSTREET BOYS* and **ARCTIC MONKEYS**
>  *MI***MYC** *CHA* **HE***EL JA***M I CAL RO***CK* **MAN***S ON***CE** - *MICHAEL JACKSON* and **MY CHEMICAL ROMANCE**
>  *SA***GO RI***MS MI***LL** *T***AZ***H* - *SAM SMITH* and **GORILLAZ**
>  *G***RAD** *U* **IO***NS* **HE***N ROS***A D***ES* - *GUNS N ROSES* and **RADIOHEAD**
>  *S***NI***T EVE M***R V***ILL***A** *ER***N** *BAN* **A***D* - *STEVE MILLER BAND* and **NIRVANA**
>  *THE***ZE** *BE* **BRA H***AT***E** *LE***AD***S* - *THE BEATLES* and **ZEBRAHEAD**
>  *KAS***H***A B***OTCH** *I***O COLA** *AN***TE** - *KASABIAN* and **HOT CHOCOLATE**
>  *LI***RY** *S***ANA***A LOPE***D** *S***AMS** - *LISA LOPES* and **RYAN ADAMS**
>  *S***MILE S***O***D** *F***A***T* **VI***C* **S***ELL* - *SOFT CELL* and **MILES DAVIS**
>  *KA***LI** *IS***L***E* **WA***R***Y** *CHI***N***E F***E***S* - *KAISER CHIEFS* and **LIL WAYNE**
>  *SU***R***F J***EDH***A N***OTCH I***S* **LI***TE* **PE***V* **P***ENS* **PERS** - *SUFJAN STEVENS* and **RED HOT CHILI PEPPERS**
>  *GE***M** *OR***E TA***G EMI***L LI***CH* **C***AEL***A** - *GEORGE MICHAEL* and **METALLICA**
>  *MA***GA BRIE***R I AH C***L***ARE* **L***Y***E** - *MARIAH CAREY* and **GABRIELLE**
>  *ME***N** *AT L***I***O***N AS I MO***A***N E***F* - *MEAT LOAF* and **NINA SIMONE**
>  *JE***F** *S***LEET WOO***S* **D***I***M***E J***AC** - *JESSIE J* and **FLEETWOOD MAC**
>  *U***K ANY EWE** *2***ST** - *U2* and **KANYE WEST**
>  *PRIN***T HE** *CE***DAR K NESS** - *PRINCE* and **THE DARKNESS**

The columns on either side contain

> years. It turns out that one of the artists in the middle released an album (or two!) during each of the years on either side of them:
>
>  Florence and the Machine - *High as Hope* (2018)
>  Neil Young - *Tonight's the Night* and *Zuma* (1975)
>  Backstreet Boys - *Millennium* (1999)
>  Arctic Monkeys - *The Car* (2022)
>  Michael Jackson - *Thriller* (1982)
>  My Chemical Romance - *I Brought You My Bullets, You Brought Me Your Love* (2002)
>  Sam Smith - *In the Lonely Hour* (2014)
>  Gorillaz - *Plastic Beach* (2010)
>  Guns N' Roses - *Use Your Illusion I* and *Use Your Illusion II* (1991)
>  Radiohead - *OK Computer* (1997)
>  Steve Miller Band - *Abracadabra* (1982)
>  Nirvana - *In Utero* (1993)
>  The Beatles - *Let it Be* (1970)
>  Zebrahead - *Walk the Plank* (2015)
>  Kasabian - *Velociraptor!* (2011)
>  Hot Chocolate - *Every 1's a Winner* (1978)
>  Lisa Lopes - *Supernova* (2001)
>  Ryan Adams - *Ryan Adams* (2014)
>  Soft Cell - *Non-Stop Erotic Cabaret* (1981)
>  Miles Davis - *In a Silent Way* (1969)
>  Kaiser Chiefs - *Yours Truly, Angry Mob* (2007)
>  Lil Wayne - *Tha Carter* (2004)
>  Sufjan Stevens - *The Avalanche* (2006)
>  Red Hot Chili Peppers - *Stadium Arcadium* (2006)
>  George Michael - *Faith* (1987)
>  Metallica - *...And Justice for All* (1988)
>  Mariah Carey - *The Emancipation of Mimi* (2005)
>  Gabrielle - *Rise* (1999)
>  Meat Loaf - *Bat Out of Hell* (1977)
>  Nina Simone - *I Put a Spell on You* and *Pastel Blues* (1965)
>  Jessie J - *Alive* (2013)
>  Fleetwood Mac - *Rumours* (1977)
>  U2 - *The Joshua Tree* (1987)
>  Kanye West - *Yeezus* (2013)
>  Prince - *Sign o' the Times* (1987)
>  The Darkness - *Pinewood Smile* (2017)

If we

> smash these album titles together (in the order they were presented in the table), disambiguating where appropriate, we get a list of body *parts* (title drop!):
>
>  TONIGHT'S THE NIGH**T|HIGH** AS HOPE
>  THE C**AR|M**ILLENNIUM
>  THRILLE**R|I B**ROUGHT YOU MY BULLETS, YOU BROUGHT ME YOUR LOVE
>  PLASTIC BEA**CH|IN** THE LONELY HOUR
>  OK COMP**UTER|US**E YOUR ILLUSION I/II
>  ABRACADA**BRA|IN** UTERO
>  WALK THE PL**ANK|LE**T IT BE
>  EVERY 1'S A WIN**NER|VE**LOCIRAPTOR!
>  SUPERN**OVA|RY**AN ADAMS
>  NON-STOP EROTIC CABA**RET|IN A** SILENT WAY
>  THA C**ARTER|Y**OURS TRULY, ANGRY MOB
>  THE AVALAN**CHE|ST**ADIUM ARCADIUM
>  FAIT**H|...AND** JUSTICE FOR ALL
>  THE EMANCIPATION OF MIM**I|RIS**E
>  BAT OUT OF HEL**L|I P**UT A SPELL ON YOU
>  A**LIVE|R**UMOURS
>  THE JOSHUA TRE**E|YE**EZUS
>  SIGN O' THE TIME**S|PINE**WOOD SMILE

Taking just

> the first letters gives us:
>
>  **TARCUBANORACHILLES**
>
>  And [tar](https://alumni.unc.edu/what-is-a-tar-heel/), [Cuban](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/cuban-heel), and [Achilles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achilles%27_heel) are all types of heels!

So the final answer is

> **HEELS**

Comment: Perfect answer - all correct, with the exact break-in I laid in there to be used :) Well done!